# jQuery checkbox selection not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form like this:

```
<form action='' onsubmit='void(0)' class="mainform">
                <label class="form3"><input type="checkbox"> One a fancy cross-browser styled checkbox</label>
                <label class="form3"><input type="checkbox"> two a fancy cross-browser styled checkbox</label>
                <label class="form3"><input type="checkbox"> Three a fancy cross-browser styled checkbox</label>
                <label class="form3"><input type="checkbox"> Four a fancy cross-browser styled checkbox</label>
                <label class="form3"><input type="checkbox"> Five a fancy cross-browser styled checkbox</label>
                <label class="form3"><input type="checkbox"> Six a fancy cross-browser styled checkbox</label>
                <label class="form3"><input type="checkbox"> Seven a fancy cross-browser styled checkbox</label>
                <label class="form3"><input type="checkbox"> eight a fancy cross-browser styled checkbox</label>
                <label class="form3"><input type="checkbox"> 9 a fancy cross-browser styled checkbox</label>
                <label class="form3"><input type="checkbox"> 10 a fancy cross-browser styled checkbox</label>
                <label class="form3"><input type="checkbox"> 11 a fancy cross-browser styled checkbox</label>
                <label class="form3"><input type="checkbox"> 12 a fancy cross-browser styled checkbox</label>
                <label class="form3"><input type="checkbox"> 13 a fancy cross-browser styled checkbox</label>
                <label class="form3"><input type="checkbox"> 14 a fancy cross-browser styled checkbox</label>
</form>
```

Now, I want to do this.
When i check and uncheck the boxes, I am updating the array 'checklist'.
If the box is checked, I set the corresponding array value to "yes", when unchecked, I set it to blank.

The problem now is, the setting of values only works once, if I uncheck a checked box and again check it, its value remains unchecked,

I am trying to do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.form3').each(function(i,e) {
   if(checklist[i] == "")
    {
        $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', false);
        $(this).appendTo($('form'));
        $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
            checklist[i]= "yes";
            $(this).closest('label').toggleClass("checkselected", this.checked);
        });
        $(this).closest('label').removeClass("checkselected");

    }
    else
    {
        $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', true);
        $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
            checklist[i]= "";
            $(this).closest('label').toggleClass("checkselected", this.checked);
        });
        $(this).closest('label').addClass("checkselected");
    }
});
});
```

Now I know that this maynot be the right way to do it because I am doing this inside the `"$('.form3').each(function(i,e)"`

How can I make it work even with mulltiple clicks to the same checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets step through your code and find out what is wrong with it.

You are setting the checkbox manually when you've clicked it, you don't need to do that, this line is done for you automatically:

```
 $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', true/false);
```

Then, you use change() incorrectly. When you do change, you set jquery to wait for an event to happen so it can do something, ie when the checkbox changes, do function(). It starts waiting for the change event **after the first click**, the next time the event happens. Change() doesn't do the change straight away. So you want it to do this:

```
 $(this).closest('label').toggleClass("checkselected", this.checked);
```

...which toggles the class of the label regardless of what the value of your checkbox is, which you've just set yourself. What actually happens? I don't know because now I'm muddled up.
If it does ever reach the toggle, you'll remove the class straight away in the first instance, or add it if its gone in the second, with this, straight afterwards, making the toggle unnecessary anyway:

```
 $(this).closest('label').add/removeClass("checkselected");
```

All this results to carnage, which you are trying to stay parallel with using an array. What a nightmare!

If you need to do something with every checkbox in something of class form3 when its value changes, do this:

```
$('.form3 :checkbox').change(function(){

    //your stuff.
    $(this).closest('label').toggleClass("checkselected", this.checked);

});
```

You can see it working here:
http://jsfiddle.net/py6bC/5/

Then whatever you were doing with the array, you can do by jquery-ing the checkboxes.

Comment: Thanks for your effort to explain in detail. Let me tell you what exactly I am trying. Basically I have this list of checkboxes. Once the user makes a few selections, I am storing their index values in an array (also using PHP Session to store the values across pages). Then if the user re-visits this page with checkboxes, I reorder the checkboxes such that the selected onces appear at the top followed by the unchecked ones. Also, the class i am appending is to show the selected checkboxes in different colour. Hope this additional information might help sovle this further :)

Comment: I've never actually done that before, but cookies or session is the right direction.

Comment: So you'd do something like var checkedelements = $('.form3 :checkbox:checked') everytime a change happened, then do an $.each on checkedelements which you pull from the cookie when the page loads again.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a good answer for this one, but presumably you are building up this array to determine which checkboxes are checked; why don't you just determine that when you need to find out?
This seems like a strange way of approaching the problem...

To fix your current code, I would have something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $('.form3').find('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {           

        var i = $(this).parent.index();

        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
           checklist[i] = "yes"; 
        }
        else {
           checklist[i] ="";
        }      
    }); 
}
```